# Getting opposite results when using indices for bitset

Tags: c++, bitset

I have a problem using bitsets from a char when I use indices.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char c = 'C';
    bitset<7> b(c);
    cout << b << endl;
    for(int j = 0; j!=7;++j){
           cout<<b[j];
        }
    return 0;

}
```

results

```
1000011
1100001
```

I must have forgotten something very simple.
Can someone explain why the results of bitset is not the same when using indices and not?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but that loop condition is not "standard", it's harder to understand the meaning of the loop, and is incredible fragile. I hope you don't use such a construct very often and especially not if sharing code with others.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop writes the least significant bit first, which is the opposite of what is done normally when writing numbers

Answer (score 0):

That is because a `std::bitset` indexing starts with the least significant bit first (at position 0).

Answer (score 0):

Read this (from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/)) :

"A basic_string whose contents are used to initialize the bitset:
The constructor parses the string reading at most n characters beginning at pos, interpreting the character values '0' and '1' as zero and one, respectively.
**Note that the least significant bit is represented by the last character read (not the first); Thus, the first bit position is read from the right-most character, and the following bits use the characters preceding this, from right to left**."

So the bitset stores the bits for 'c' from right to left , and you are accessing the bits from left to right.

Answer (score -1):

```
1000011   
+     +   
|     |   
v     v   
b[6]  b[0]
```

Do you get it?